# One view for edit and add page with reactive Form

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I want to use one angular component to edit and show the details of a customer (used as an example).

Normally I implement a reactive form (with ~ 15 Controls) and disable all controls, that should be not editable like shown here:

```
form = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: [""],
  birthday: [{value:"", disabled: true}],
...
)};
```

The problem is: if I want to use the view with its form to show the customer's details, the input-fields would also appear the disabled look/style.

In order to prevent that, I am thinking of removing the disabled tag from the FromControls and implementing the following logic in the HTML of the component:

```
<input matInput formControlName="birthday" readonly [ngClass]="{'disabled-look': this.isEditMode === true}">

// css
.disabled-look{
color: gray;
}
```

Now the input field is always readonly.
In case the view is in editMode the input field gets an style that makes ist look ineditable.
If the view is not in edit mode, the input fields are readonly but are not displayed disabled, which was what I wanted to achieve.

Is there anything wrong with using this approach? Is there a smarter way to do it?

Thanks in Advance! :D

### Edit:

Another approach based on @Gonzalo's isEditMode, would be
`<input *ngIf="this.isEditMode" matInput formControlName="birthday">`
`<input *ngIf="!this.isEditMode" matInput value="{{this.customer.birthday | date}}">`

And add the disabled tag back to the FormControl again

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
<input type="text" [readonly]="!isEditMode" [disabled]="isEditMode">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use different inputs based on `isEditMode`.

```
<input *ngIf="this.isEditMode" matInput formControlName="birthday" disabled>
<input *ngIf="!this.isEditMode" matInput formControlName="birthday" readonly>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I also thought of this one. But using disabled in the html of the form causes the following warning:


`looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive [..] We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.

      Example:
      form = new FormGroup({
        first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
        last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
      }); `